# Есть ли альтернативы puppeteer для golang?

Tags: golang, google-chrome, less, puppeteer

Есть ли альтернативы puppeteer для golang? Т.е. средства с помощью которых можно запускать хром в headless режиме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть похожий. Так же использует Chrome DevTools Protocol
[chromedp](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp)

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли.